# How can I find same values in a list and group together a new list?

Tags: python, list, duplicates, append

From this list:

```
N = [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5]
```

I'm trying to create:

```
L = [[1],[2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4,4],[5,5,5,5,5]]
```

Any value which is found to be the same is grouped into it's own sublist.
Here is my attempt so far, I'm thinking I should use a `while` loop?

```
global n

n = [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5] #Sorted list
l = [] #Empty list to append values to

def compare(val):
   """ This function receives index values
   from the n list (n[0] etc) """
   
   global valin
   valin = val

   global count
   count = 0

    for i in xrange(len(n)):
        if valin == n[count]: # If the input value i.e. n[x] == n[iteration]
            temp = valin, n[count]
             l.append(temp) #append the values to a new list
             count +=1
        else:
          count +=1
    

for x in xrange (len(n)):
    compare(n[x]) #pass the n[x] to compare function
```

Comment: *Here is my attempt so far* ... Please mention if you have faced any problems with your code.

Comment: Why store all the numbers? Why not just collapse it into a list of tuples containing two values. The number itself and the number of times that number occurs.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Someone mentions for `N=[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1]` it will get `[[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [1]]`

In other words, when numbers of the list isn't in order or it is a mess list, it's not available.

So I have better answer to solve this problem.

```
from collections import Counter

N = [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5]
C = Counter(N)

print [ [k,]*v for k,v in C.items()]
```

Answer (score 55):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

N = [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5]

print([list(j) for i, j in groupby(N)])
```

**Output:**

```
[[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]
```

Side note: Prevent from using global variable when you don't **need** to.

Comment: Note: the list needs to be sorted according to the same key used by groupby to achieve the result expected in the question. Otherwise e.g. for `N=[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1]` you will get `[[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [1]]`.

Comment: @Sam Bruns . Your method is not stable when , for example,`N` has random values. If you want to check what I am trying to say, just put `random.shuffle(N)` right after you create list `N`. Then, you will see *output* is not the same while the code by @Burger King is stable.

Comment: @Spider: The array containing random values is *not* in any way a requirement specified by the OP. Please make sure you fully understand the question before commenting.

Comment: @SamBruns I made exactly sure by saying: "your method is not stable" and there is nothing wrong to complement your answer in order to show the audience that if someone wants to use in any cases like that. Your method definitely fails when it comes to "un-sorted" list and ... you make sure please, my comment what I m trying to say.

Comment: @Spider: What you define as "stable" and "not stable" is arbitrary here. Maybe the OP **DO** wants the solution to behave that way. One can think of many use cases where grouping all the values into a single list is not wanted. While the behavior you're pointing out can be mentioned as a note (as it already was in the first comment), it cannot in any way be defined as *not stable*. Please don't make your assumptions... requirements.

Comment: This is so good

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) along with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
>>> l =  [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5]
>>> [list(v) for k,v in itertools.groupby(l)]
[[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]
```

This can be assigned to the variable `L` as in

```
L = [list(v) for k,v in itertools.groupby(l)]
```

Answer (score 6):

You're overcomplicating this.

What you want to do is: for each value, if it's the same as the last value, just append it to the list of last values; otherwise, create a new list. You can translate that English directly to Python:

```
new_list = []
for value in old_list:
    if new_list and new_list[-1][0] == value:
        new_list[-1].append(value)
    else:
        new_list.append([value])
```

There are even simpler ways to do this if you're willing to get a bit more abstract, e.g., by using the grouping functions in `itertools`. But this should be easy to understand.

---

If you really need to do this with a `while` loop, you can translate any `for` loop into a `while` loop like this:

```
for value in iterable:
    do_stuff(value)

iterator = iter(iterable)
while True:
    try:
        value = next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    do_stuff(value)
```

Or, if you know the iterable is a sequence, you can use a slightly simpler `while` loop:

```
index = 0
while index < len(sequence):
    value = sequence[index]
    do_stuff(value)
    index += 1
```

But both of these make your code less readable, less Pythonic, more complicated, less efficient, easier to get wrong, etc.

Comment: Really nice answer (I like brute-force), But can you think of a way using a `while` loop? In OP's words *I'm thinking I should use a while loop?*

Comment: @BhargavRao: Well, you can always translate any `for` loop into a `while` loop. But why do you want to?

Comment: For this problem the `for` loop is better suited. Unlike C, py translations are not that straight-forward, though they are quite easy. I just asked to give the OP a fair idea of the `while` loop and it's complications. D̶o̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶s̶i̶d̶e̶r̶ ̶d̶o̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶s̶p̶a̶r̶e̶ ̶t̶i̶m̶e̶ Well good one there :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using numpy too:

```
import numpy as np

N = np.array([1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5])
counter = np.arange(1, np.alen(N))
L = np.split(N, counter[N[1:]!=N[:-1]])
```

The advantage of this method is when you have another list which is related to N and you want to split it in the same way.

Answer (score -2):

Another slightly different solution that doesn't rely on itertools:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def group(items):
    """
    groups a sorted list of integers into sublists based on the integer key
    """
    if len(items) == 0:
        return []

    grouped_items = []
    prev_item, rest_items = items[0], items[1:]

    subgroup = [prev_item]
    for item in rest_items:
        if item != prev_item:
            grouped_items.append(subgroup)
            subgroup = []
        subgroup.append(item)
        prev_item = item

    grouped_items.append(subgroup)
    return grouped_items

print group([1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5])
# [[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]
```