# How to sum consecutive duplicates in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm doing some practice problems on internet to apply for an internships and got in to a hard one. The problem is sum consecutive numbers that are the same.

example: [1,1,3,4,4,5] ---> [2,3,8,5]

```
 def sum_consecutive(s):
    p = []
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] == s[i-1]:
            p.append(s[i] + s[i-1])
            p.remove(s[i])
        elif s[i] != s[i-1]:
            p.append(s[i])
    return p
```

when running the code above on [1,4,4,4,0,4,3,3,1] it should return [1,12,0,4,6,1] instead it returns

in sum_consecutive(s)

```
    if s[i] == s[i-1]:
             p.append(s[i] + s[i-1])
             p.remove(s[i]) #This line is the problem
    elif s[i] != s[i-1]:
             p.append(s[i])
```

Error:

```
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Comment: Suggestion: Since you're applying for internships, learn how to debug code. For starters, read [Eric Lippert's How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Learn how to use the print function and the debugger, and you'll have a higher chance of succeeding in interviews.

Comment: `itertools.groupby` should help.

Comment: When `i=0` You will end up comparing index 0 with index -1 (which is the last element) and hence you get the error (at that time `p` is empty)

Comment: According to your error you have `p.remove(s[i]-1)` somewhere in your code, but it's not in the code you posted.

Comment: @khelwood sorry I made a mistake when I was writing this question, but you can try to run it and you'll see this error.

Comment: The first iteration of the loop is wrong.  Change `range(len(s))` to `range(1, len(s))` to fix it.  Assuming you fix that bug, consider what happens if the first two elements match.  You will append their sum to `p`.  Then you will try to remove the first element to `p`.  Well, unless they're both zero, it's not going to be there.  So of course you will get an error.  Just think it through.  Consider all the cases.  It's a very simple problem.

Comment: [relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30293071/python-find-same-values-in-a-list-and-group-together-a-new-list)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a variable to keep track of the last seen value, then add it to the current index if it is the same.

```
def sum_consecutive(s):
    p = s[:1]   # final list
    cur = s[0]  # keep track of last seen value

    for i in s[1:]:  # your exercise: replace this with `range` 
        if i == cur:
            p[-1] += i
        else:
            p.append(i)
            cur = i

    return p
```

```
sum_consecutive([1, 4, 4, 4, 0, 4, 3, 3, 1])
# [1, 12, 0, 4, 6, 1]
```

---

As a bonus, let's not forget the stdlib exists, so you can use [**`itertools.groupby`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to do this in one line.

```
from itertools import groupby
[sum(g) for _, g in groupby([1, 4, 4, 4, 0, 4, 3, 3, 1])]
# [1, 12, 0, 4, 6, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def sum_consecutive(input_list):
i = 0
res = []
while(i < len(input_list)):
    j = i
    while(j < len(input_list) and input_list[i]==input_list[j]):
        j = j + 1

    res.append(input_list[i]*(j-i))
    i = j
return res
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this funtion, it may be interresting as it's very easy to understand :

```
def count_occ(L):
    p = []
    count = 1
    for i, j in zip(L[:-1], L[1:]):
        if i != j:
            p.append(count*i)
            count = 1
        else:
            count += 1
    p.append(count*L[-1])
    return p
```