# How can I count and group the elements of an array that are the same?

Tags: python, graphene-python

I have in my code an array that has a lot of similar values, as example

```
A=[1,1,2,2,2,4,5,6,6,6]
```

but my array is way more long and complicated.
I want to group the values that are the same and count how many there are from this value.
Is there any specific way to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find same values in a list and group together a new list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30293071/how-can-i-find-same-values-in-a-list-and-group-together-a-new-list)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
from collections import Counter

A=[1,1,2,2,2,4,5,6,6,6]

a = dict(Counter(A))

print(a)
```

which gives a dictionary showing the unique values and their count:

```
{1: 2, 2: 3, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pandas library for this.

```
import pandas as pd

A=[1,1,2,2,2,4,5,6,6,6]
count = pd.Series(A).value_counts()
print("elements count")
print(count)
```

Result will come up as below:

```
elements count
2         3
6         3
1         2
4         1
5         1
```