# How to group the elements of the same value in a list in a sorted way

Tags: python

For example, if we have:

```
arr= [1,4,5,1,6,4,7,5]
```

How can I group the items so the result is `[1,1],[4,4],[5,5],[6],[7]`?

Comment: What if the input was `arr= [1,5,4,1,6,5,7,4]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find same values in a list and group together a new list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30293071/how-can-i-find-same-values-in-a-list-and-group-together-a-new-list)

Answer (score 2):

Using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

arr= [1,4,5,1,6,4,7,5]

out = [list(g) for _, g in groupby(sorted(arr))]
```

Output: `[[1, 1], [4, 4], [5, 5], [6], [7]]`

But sorting is O(n*logn).

For an O(n) solution using an intermediate dictionary:

```
d = {}
for x in arr:
    d.setdefault(x, []).append(x)
    
out = list(d.values())
```

*NB. this doesn't "sort" the values here, only groups them.*

Output: `[[1, 1], [4, 4], [5, 5], [6], [7]]`

Comment: @DanielHao yes `itertools` is great, but I added a second approach that is better IMO ;)

Comment: @Daniel I just realized the "*in a sorted way*" is ambiguous, I'm not sure if OP really meant sorted or just grouped. I requested a clarification

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from collections

```py
from collections import Counter

arr= [1,4,5,1,6,4,7,5]

counts = Counter(arr)
group = [[item] * count for item, count, in counts.items()]
print(group)
```

---

```
[[1, 1], [4, 4], [5, 5], [6], [7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to aggregate the values and then convert its values to a list:

```
arr= [1,4,5,1,6,4,7,5]

D = dict()
D.update( (n,D.get(n,[])+[n]) for n in arr )

result = list(D.values())  # or sorted(D.values()) if needed

print(result) # [[1, 1], [4, 4], [5, 5], [6], [7]]
```

This will preserve the original order of first appearance of each distinct value (which happens to already be in ascending order of value as well in your example).  If the first occurrences are not sorted you can sort the result afterward or use the groupby method on the sorted list:

```
from itertools import groupby

result = [ g for _,[*g,] in groupby(sorted(arr)) ]

print(result) # [[1, 1], [4, 4], [5, 5], [6], [7]]
```